# Use of おく and 方 in this sentence

Tags: grammar, translation, usage, nouns

このたなの一番おくの方にございます。

- They are at the far end of this shelf.

This is an example sentence from one of my textbooks but I don't understand what おく means and I'm a bit confused on the use of 方 as well, especially when looking at the translation.

Comment: [奥{おく} in the Progressive J-E Dictionary](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/8140/m1u/%E5%A5%A5/)　-　[方{ほう} in the same dictionary](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/68957/m1u/%E6%96%B9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`奥{おく}` is the part far away from the "entrance" of a thing, so it could be translated by `bottom` or `back` for example depending of the type of object (e.g. a vase or a room). Or `end` in the case of a shelf ; it will most likely refer to the part the farther from the speaker / listener in this case. So `一番{いちばん}おく` would indeed be the `far end` of the shelf here.

What does `の方{ほう}` add then ?? `の方{ほう}` can indicate a direction, as in `奥{おく}の方{ほう}へお進{すす}みください` (`please proceed _towards_ the back`), but can also be used to refer to an area or more generally a thing in a *vague* manner. I think the sentence could also be translated to `They are _towards_ the far end of this shelf`. It doesn't make a big difference though and I guess that's why it is omitted in your textbook translation.
It could also be omitted in Japanese, `一番{いちばん}おくにございます` is perfectly valid but in this case it really refers to a precise location and you wouldn't expect to find anything after it (meaning they're the last items on the shelf).

---

Note: `の方{ほう}` being used to refer vaguely to things, leads to some people abusing it in an attempt to sound less "harsh" (intending to be more polite). You may hear it a lot in some restaurants for example. It doesn't add any meaning more than making the statement generally more ambiguous though, and is considered poor style.

Comment: Considering the context of the sentence: a store assistant directing a customer to an item, this use of の方 to sound more polite makes complete sense then.

Comment: In this case, especially since it's taken from a text book, I guess the `far end` isn't the _exact_ position of the items and `の方` serves to indicate the direction or at least an approximate position (which is more or less the same). My note was referring to some people _abusing_ this expression and using it even when designing very precise things ; for example `メニューのほう、お下{さ}げいたします。` (roughly `let me remove the menus`), where `の方` is completely useless and even wrong. I think you can ignore this (wrong) usage of the word for now, you shouldn't encounter it in a text book anyway.

Answer (score 2):

おく means the interior of something but is often used to mean "in the back". This is the use of 方 (ほう) meaning a direction. So put together you get something like "toward the deepest" part of the shelf, which you textbook has chosen to express as the "far end".